# Unnamed Pipes in UNIX child message doesn't get received by father while sending a string in C

Tags: c, unix, process, pipe

I have two processes that I have created with two unnamed pipes, but I can't figure out why I can't send messages from the sons to the father. It appears that the father doesn't receive the string. The son is sending the right string; it just doesn't reach destination, can't figure out why ...
Can you explain to me?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>

    #define max_chars_string 1000
    #define n_childs 2

    pid_t childs[n_childs];
    int channel[n_childs][2];

    void read_lines(char * filename, char (*pointer)[max_chars_string],int init_read,int n_lines);
    void get_strings_hash(char (*pointer_strings)[max_chars_string],char (*pointer_hashes)[max_chars_string],int total_lines);

    void worker(int mypipe,char filename[],int n_lines){ // meter as funcoes de ler passwords no filho
        int resources[2];// numero de linhas que cada processo tem de ler
        int i = 0;

        //definicao arrays
        char strings_hashes[n_lines][max_chars_string];//aray de string com as strings lidas do ficheiro
            char * pointer_strings = &strings_hashes[0][0];//ponteiro para o inicio do array das hashes

        read_lines(filename,strings_hashes,0,n_lines); // le as strings do ficheiro e passa para o array

        for(i = 0;i<n_lines;i++){
            printf("%s \n",strings_hashes[i]);
        }
        printf("[%d] My parent is: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());

        //open pipe to write and close pipe to read

        close(channel[mypipe][0]);
        i = 0;
        int incr = 0;
        while (i<n_lines) {
            printf("[Son] Password sent e  %s: \n",strings_hashes[incr]);
             write(channel[mypipe][1], strings_hashes[incr], strlen(strings_hashes[incr]));
             incr++;
             i++;
        }
        exit(0);
    }

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        char *filename;
        int status;//status do processos filho
        int resources[2];// numero de linhas que cada processo tem de ler
        int n_lines; //numero de linhas do ficheiro
        int i = 0;

          // Create a pipe
        filename = (char*)malloc(strlen(argv[1])*sizeof(char)+1);

        if(argc !=3){
            fprintf(stderr, "Usage : %s [text_file] [cores]",argv[0]);
            exit(0);
        }

        strcpy(filename,argv[1]);

        char get_file [strlen(filename)];
        strcpy(get_file,filename);

     // start the processes
       for(i = 0; i <atoi(argv[2]);i++){
            pipe(channel[i]);
            childs[i] = fork();

            if(childs[i] == -1){
               perror("Failed to fork");
               return 1;
           }
           if (childs[i] == 0)
           {
              worker(i,get_file,n_lines);
           }
           close(channel[i][1]);
       }

               i = 0;
               int k = 0;
               int fd;
               fd_set read_set;
               FD_ZERO(&read_set);
               char string_lida [30];

               // working father
               printf("[%d] I'm the father!\n", getpid());
               printf("[Father]orking ...\n");

                //unammed_pipes connection
                while(k<n_childs){

                    FD_SET(channel[0][0], &read_set);
                    for(i=0;i<n_childs;i++){
                            FD_SET(channel[i][0], &read_set);
                            if(fd<channel[i][0]){      fd=channel[i][0];
                            }
                        }

                    if(select(fd+1,&read_set,NULL,NULL,NULL)>0){
                        for(i=0;i<n_childs;i++){
                            if(FD_ISSET(channel[i][0], &read_set)){                    
                                read(channel[i][0],string_lida,strlen(string_lida));
                                printf("[Father]pipe %d - string lida:%s\n",i,string_lida);

                                k++;                 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    fd=1;
                }
              //
              //waiting for childs ...
            for(i=0;i<n_childs;i++){
                wait(&status);
                printf("waiting for childs \n");
              }

      return 0;
    }  


    void get_strings_hash(char (*pointer_strings)[max_chars_string],char (*pointer_hashes)[max_chars_string],int total_lines)//vai ao array de strings e corta a parte de hash e mete num array
    {
        int i = 0;
        char *strings;
        char *hash;

        for(i = 0;i<total_lines;i++){
                strings = (char*)malloc(strlen(pointer_strings)*sizeof(char)+1);
                strcpy(strings,*pointer_strings);
                hash = (char*)malloc(strlen(pointer_strings)*sizeof(char)+1);
                find_hash(strings,hash);
                strcpy(*pointer_hashes,hash);
            pointer_hashes++;
            pointer_strings++;
        }

    }


    void read_lines(char * filename, char (*pointer)[max_chars_string],int init_read,int n_lines){ 
        FILE *fp;
        char str[max_chars_string];
        int i =0;

        if((fp = fopen(filename, "r"))==NULL) {
          printf("Cannot open file.\n");
          exit(1);
        }

        if(init_read>0 && init_read<=n_lines){
         for(i = 0;i<init_read;i++){
             fgets(str, sizeof str, fp);
           for(i = init_read;i<n_lines;i++){
               fgets(str, sizeof str, fp);
               strcpy(*pointer, str); //copia para a posicao actula do ponteiro
               pointer++;
           }
         }
        }
        if(init_read<=n_lines && init_read==0){
           for(i = init_read;i<n_lines;i++){
                fgets(str, sizeof str, fp);
               strcpy(*pointer, str); //copia para a posicao actula do ponteiro
               pointer++;
           }
         }


      fclose(fp);
    }
```

Comment: You've got a buffer overflow bug at: `char get_file[strlen(filename)]; strcpy(get_file,filename);`.  You need to use `strlen(filename)+1`...if you need to copy the file name for a second time, which is unlikely.  In fact, it isn't clear why you need to copy the file name at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,i forgot i had two variables repeated,but i was testing the child to see if it read the files and it did read everything from the file, so there must be other problem ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is this line:

```
read(channel[i][0],string_lida,strlen(string_lida));
```

since you don't initialize `string_lida`, the `strlen` might return anything, but I'm guessing its returning 0 (the string is empty), so you never read anything.  You want `sizeof(string_lida)` instead.  You then need to manually NUL-terminate the string in `string_lida` as the read won't do so.  So you need to check the return value of `read` to see how many characters were read (or if it was an EOF).

You also only wait for a total of n_childs strings to be read -- if each child sends more than one string, you won't get most of them.

Comment: thanks for the help, now the father does receive the strings but also some strange chars is that because of the size of the string doesnt match the string sent?if thats the case how can i fix this?Also what changes do i need to make to make the father wait for all the strings of the child?